Logarithm approximation for $\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{A}{B+Cx})}$
I accidentally found that for $x\geq0$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\ln(1+\frac{A}{B+Cx})}\approx \frac{B+Cx}{A}+0.5
\end{equation}
$A,B,C >0$, but I do not know what the intuition behind that. Thank you for helping.

$\dfrac{1}{\ln(1+x)}$ has a Laurent expansion $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{2}+O(x)$.

Work with $\lim_{x\to \infty} xln(1+1/x)) = 1$, which is known.

You are not telling us that $x$ is supposed to tend to whatever.

@AnneBauval sorry, for $x\geq0$.

@AngaeMT thank you, but what is the $O(x)$, and do you have reference for that.

$x\ge0$ is not sufficient. $x\to?$ ($0$?, $\infty$?, ...)

@OsamaThabet  you can simply treat $O(x)$ as "terms with degree higher than $x$", since the Laurent series holds at around $x=0$, usually the term with $x$ or higher degree will vanish, which is not important, so we write $O(x)$ here, and this also matches with your investigation.
